how to deactivate multiple Lightning Flows with clicks not code?
we have a package we need to remove and the package comes with a LOT of flows (20). Salesforce says we need to deactivate the flows prior to the uninstall operation.
How do you uninstall multiple flows at once?

Unfortunately, Salesforce does not provide a native way to bulk deactivate flows directly.

You will have to open each flow individually.
Click on each flow you want to deactivate.
Open the flow version you want to deactivate.
Once inside the flow's detail page, click the Deactivate link on the flow version. This option will only be available if the flow is activated. 

You will have to repeat the process for each of the 20 flows.
